# Accessing HDFS from Pig UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have a Pig Java UDF, in which I'm trying to access the filesystem to read a group of files into a HashMap. However, when I call `UDFContext.getUDFContext().getJobConf()` either in the constructor, or in the body of a method that later gets executed, I get `null` as the output. What is the proper format to get the Configuration for a Job from within an EvalFunc?

Comment: Could you share some piece of code? JobConf is available only on the backend (inside the method calls EvalFunc.exec(), LoadFunc.getNext())

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `@MonitoredUDF` by any chance? In my case I was able to solve the issue by removing the Annotation from the class.